# Use HTML string from Server Requets, and create the web page without saving it a file [in C#]

Tags: c#, html

I´m sending the value of a variable via POST to a PHP page in C#. I get the data stream from the server that has all the web page in HTML with the value of the POST. This information is stored in a `string` variable.

I would like to open a browser and show the web page (maybe using  `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("URL")`), without having to save it in a file, this is showing the page in the moment and, when the browser is closed, no file is stored in the server.

Any idea?

Comment: You're doing this in what context?  Are you doing this on the client machine in a winforms app or on a web app?

Comment: Well, I´m using a BioStation for fingerprints. When an user puts his fingerprint and he is identified, I send some information via POST to a page that is NOT in the localhost. I retrieve the results -product of that POST var- in a string and I would like to print the webpage in a browser. The fimgerprint device is in C#, and the page is in PHP.

Comment: The fingerprint device APP is in C# you mean - I presume it's running on the client machine that is connected to the fingerprint device?  So you're talking about a windows forms app?

Comment: Correct, the app is in C#, and yes, is a windows forms app (being developed in Visual Studio 10'). Also, is running on the client machine that is connected to the fingerprint device.

Answer (score 0):

Drop a WebBrowser control into a new form webBrowser1 and set its DocumentTextProperty to your result html

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = ("<html><body>hello world</body></html>");
```

source:

```
<html><body>hello world</body></html>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to show the info in a PHP page, and not in the C# app?

Comment: You mean from the PHP page you're posting to?  That's on the server, right?  You want there to be a page displayed on the server, not to the user with the fingerprint app?

Comment: Yes, in the server -well, all will be localhost-, the page should be showed in a PHP page and NOT in the fingerprint app.

Comment: I am becoming concerned that you're using terms here that you don't really understand.  For instance, "showing in a PHP page" doesn't really make sense.  PHP pages are used to GENERATE output, which is viewed in a browser component (be that a stand alone browser or a component in an app).  Secondly, it sounds like you want the web server (localhost or otherwise, doesn't matter) to open the browser, which is never a sound practice.

Comment: Sorry. I will try to explain myself: a) I send a POST variable in C#, and the string retrieved, which has an HTML page is stored in a string variable. b) I need to output that HTML page, with the result of the data, in a browser -firefox, etc.- WITHOUT saving the HTML pager in a file.

Comment: Which I just showed you how to do.  But you can't pass HTML into a browser directly unless you own that browser process, which means you're either in the browser already or you have a browser component.  Now what you could do is use a querystring instead of a post, and have the browser launch with that URL including the querystring...

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to do that in an agnostic way.

If you simply wanted to open the URL in a browser, then using the [`Process` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) would work.

Unfortunately, in your case, you already have the content from creating the POST to the server, and you really want to stream that response in your application to the browser.

It's possible among the *some* browsers, but it's not able to be done in an agnostic way (and it's complicated even when targeting a specific browser).

To complicate matters, you want the browser to believe that the stream you are sending it is really coming from the server, when in reality, it's not.

I believe that your best bet would be to save the response to the file system in a temp file.  However, before you do, add the [`<base>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag to the file with the URL that the file came from.  This way, relative URLs will resolve correctly when rendered in the browser.

Then, just open the temporary file in the browser using the `Process` class.

Comment: well, I think I should use this solution, although didn´t want to do temp files. Nevertheless, is a good solution. Thanks